# How to use httpcore in Java to upload media to Twitter?

Tags: java, android, twitter

Using twitter4j etc. blows my dex limit; so I have to roll my own twitter requests in Java using httpcore.
I've succeeded all the way through getting an access token and doing a statuses update.
Now I need to upload a photo, so I'm trying the following.

I have already looked at dozens of StackOverflow articles, plus Twitter's own Forums, but I just
cannot find useful help.

Relevant twitter documentation is [here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/media/upload-chunked)
and [here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/uploading-media), but it fails to answer many basic questions.

Here's the first approach:

```
BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest httpEntityEnclosingRequest = new BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest( POST, "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json" );
// Since we setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),
// it seems reasonable that we should send a UrlEncodedFormEntity.
List<NameValuePair> formparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("command", "INIT"));
formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("media_type", "image/png"));
formparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("total_bytes", "6046"));
UrlEncodedFormEntity urlEncodedFormEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formparams, UTF_8);
httpEntityEnclosingRequest.setEntity( urlEncodedFormEntity );
```

Here's the second approach:

```
StringEntity stringEntity;
stringEntity = new StringEntity( "command=INIT&media_type=image%2Fjpeg&total_bytes=6046", UTF_8);
stringEntity.setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httpEntityEnclosingRequest.setEntity(stringEntity);
```

Both approaches proceed on to this code:

```
urlEncodedFormEntity.setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httpEntityEnclosingRequest.setParams(httpParams);
httpEntityEnclosingRequest.addHeader("Authorization", authorization_header_string);
httpEntityEnclosingRequest.addHeader("Content-Type","x-www-form-urlencoded" );
HttpContext httpContext = getHttpContext(httpHost, httpClientConnection);
HttpResponse httpResponse = getHttpResponse( httpParams, httpClientConnection, httpContext, httpEntityEnclosingRequest);
```

Both approaches get the response:
{"errors":[{"code":38,"message":"media parameter is missing."}]}.

What's wrong with this code? Can anybody help out?

Comment: Are you sure that you add the content to the body and not as "get" parameters? I recommend to use [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) for simplify your request.

Comment: Thanx Kevinrob. The real problem is not with httpcore or client; it's with the very brittle and poorly documented Twitter server.